# Windows CTRL+ALT+DEL kills Java thread

Tags: java, multithreading

How Windows <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> works?
What impact it has for running Java program threads?

I'm running small Java program with thread and after <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> thread is killed.
**How to prevent this?**

Comment: How are you testing this ? I'm curious as if you actually can detect the thread dying right after your Ctrl+Alt+Del

Comment: Which version of windows? How are you running your program? Does the user pressing ctrl+alt+del have to do anything else to kill it, or is it enough to just press the sequence?

Answer (score 4):

You mean; <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> into the task manager, then select your Java process and the user ends it?

You can't prevent it and you shouldn't.
The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> mechanism is in place for processes which don't behave like they should and should be 'killed'.

If your process ends when the user just presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> then something is wrong, that shouldn't be happening.